# How to take keep parts of an array and form a new array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5 app.
In this app I have connected to the Google Calendar API.
The connection works fine and I get a list of calendars back.
What I need to do is to get the Id and Summary of this JSON object that I get back from Google.

**This is what I get**

```
    [{
        "kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry",
        "etag": "\"1483552200690000\"",
        "id": "xxx.com_asae@group.calendar.google.com",
        "summary": "My office calendar",
        "description": "For office meeting",
        "location": "344 Common st",
        "colorId": "8",
        "backgroundColor": "#16a765",
        "foregroundColor": "#000000",
        "accessRole": "owner",
        "defaultReminders": [],
        "conferenceProperties": {
            "allowedConferenceSolutionTypes": [
                "hangoutsMeet"
            ]
        }
    },
{
        "kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry",
        "etag": "\"1483552200690000\"",
        "id": "xxx.com_asae@group.calendar.google.com",
        "summary": "My office calendar",
        "description": "For office meeting",
        "location": "344 Common st",
        "colorId": "8",
        "backgroundColor": "#16a765",
        "foregroundColor": "#000000",
        "accessRole": "owner",
        "defaultReminders": [],
        "conferenceProperties": {
            "allowedConferenceSolutionTypes": [
                "hangoutsMeet"
            ]
        }
    }]
```

**This is what I want to end up with**

```
[{
    "id": "xxx.com_asae@group.calendar.google.com",
    "title": "My office calendar",
}]
```

The purpose of this is that I want to populate a selectbox using Selectize plugin

Comment: You can combine `Array#map` with `Hash#slice` to achieve this.

Comment: How can I do this? I am not very familiar with Map or Slice.

Comment: But you can find the documentation on them and learn what they do / how they work?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - a perhaps a `transform_keys` since `summary` needs to change to `title`?

Comment: @jvillian wouldn't that be a misuse of `transform_keys`? It's for symbolizing all keys or something like that.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Why the Hash#slice?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - yeah, maybe. My brain is unidling.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: because I didn't notice the summary->title :)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the desierd keys with the select method:

```
responde = {your_json_response}
expected = [response[0].select{|k,v| ['id','title'].include?(k)}]
```

`response[0]` retrieves the hash, and the select compares each key with the ones you want and returns a hash with only those key: value pairs.

EDIT: I missed that you don't have a "title" key on the original response, I would do this then:

```
response = {your_json_response}
h = response[0]
expected = [{'id' => h['id'], 'title' => h['summary']}]
```

EDIT 2: Sorry, the first example was not clear that there would be multiple hashes

```
expected = response.map{|h| {'id' => h['id'], 'title' => h['summary']}}
```

`map` iterates over each element of `response` and returns the result of the block applied for each iteration as an array, so the blocks is apllied to each `h` and it generates a new hash from it

Comment: You misunderstood the question.. :)

Comment: I only get one of the items return with above solution. I just included one in my example to make it easier to view.

Comment: check my edit, I didn't get that you could have more than one hash

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve removing of certain keys in your hash is by using `Hash#reject` method:

```
response = { your_json_response }
expected = [response[0].reject {|k| k != :id && k != :summary}]
```

The original response remains unchanged while a mutated copy of the original response is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this approach.

```
expected = response.each { |h| h.keep_if { |k, _| k == :id || k == :summary } }
```

It returns just the required pairs:

```
# => [{:id=>"xxx.com_asae@group.calendar.google.com", :summary=>"My office calendar"}, {:id=>"xxx.com_asae@group.calendar.google.com", :summary=>"My office calendar"}]
```

To remove duplicates, just do `expected.uniq`

If you need to change the key name :summary to :title do:

```
expected = expected.each { |h| h[:title] = h.delete(:summary) }
```

One liner

```
expected = response.each { |h| h.keep_if { |k, _| k == :id || k == :summary } }.each { |h| h[:title] = h.delete(:summary) }.uniq
```

Of course, maybe it is better to move .uniq as first method `expected = response.uniq.each { .....`